# Paperclip Progress bar

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I have been looking around for something that shows the progress of an upload using Paperclip. I can't find any solutions is there any out there? If not is there any particular progress uploader that can be recommended?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I  have found an answer. 
http://github.com/pkordel/uploadify_paperclip_demo

This seems to be a working and easy to implement.

Answer (score 1):

SWFUpload is the thing you should be searching for.

Comment: are there any tutorials on how to implement it with paperclip?

Comment: I did, I have tried this one http://jimneath.org/2008/05/15/swfupload-paperclip-and-ruby-on-rails/ but its very out of date and I can't get it to work.

Comment: Well I think I used that one as well and had it work. Maybe if you post concrete code and errors we can get somewhere - but I really can't help you like this. It is doable as I do currently have an app that does just exactly that (and more, like multiple file upload) so if you post concrete problems I can help you.

Comment: Ah and yes, it's not typically the simplest thing to do - especially if you need users to be logged in.